# Wordpress - Update User Profile function

Tags: wordpress, function

I have the following function in my functions.php file:-

```
function apply_for_job() {

    $job_id = $_GET['job_id'];

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $prev_value = get_field('applied_jobs');

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'applied_jobs', $job_id);


}
add_filter('init' ,'apply_for_job');
```

When I load: http://distinct.dev/apply_for_job/?job_id=323

This updates 'applied_jobs' field to: 323 as expected.

However, when I go on my user profile page it sets the value to 'NULL'

Any ideas why?

Comment: @Sumit - Users doesn't have an idea though does it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's considered 'best practise' but I managed to fix it by changing the above to:-

```
function apply_for_job() {

    if (!empty($_GET['job_id'])) {
        $job_id = $_GET['job_id'];
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'applied_jobs', $job_id);


}
if (!empty($_GET['job_id'])) {
add_filter('init' ,'apply_for_job');
}
```

By adding the `if (!empty($_GET['job_id'])) {` around the filter and `$_GET['job_id']`, otherwise it would be updating regardless of what page is being accessed.